# Jquery gradual zoom on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image slideshow on my site that fades images in and out through the transition. I am now however wanting to "zoom in" on the image at the same time. The easiest way I can think of doing this is to increase the size of the image gradually but have the overflow hidden. How would I do this while maintaining the shape and size of the image on my site?

JS

```
$(function() {
  slideShow();
  var imgArray = [
      'Images/image1.jpg',
      'Images/image2.jpg',
      'Images/image3.jpg',
      'Images/image4.jpg',
      'Images/image5.jpg',
      'Images/image6.jpg',
      'Images/image7.jpg',
      'Images/image8.jpg'
    ],
  curIndex = 0;
  imgDuration = 5000;

  function slideShow() {
  $("#slider")
    .fadeOut('slow', function() {
        var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imgArray[curIndex]).on('load', function() 
        {
                $("#slider")
                    .html(img)
                    .fadeIn('normal', function() 
                    {
                        curIndex++;
                        if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
                            curIndex = 0;
                        }
                        setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
                    });
            });
    });
  }

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider" style="height:68vh; width: 99vw;"></div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```